# Please, help identify this sea worm

Tags: species-identification, zoology, marine-biology, invertebrates

[image]

It was found in Malta, in a puddle by the sea.
It left a lot of tiny hair on the shoes (which we removed thoroughly without touching them).

I didn’t have any coins with me so I put keys for scale.

Comment: Apparently a "bristle worm" , there are many kinds. When I had salt water aquariums, there were at least 3 varieties in the gravel that were introduced with "live" rock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a **Mediterranean Bearded Fireworm** (*Hermodice carunculata*).

[image]

Source: [The Malta Independent](https://www.independent.com.mt/articles/2019-07-09/local-news/Beware-This-little-fellow-could-cause-you-some-pain-6736210623)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermodice_carunculata):

> Bearded fireworms are usually 15 centimetres in average length, but can reach up to 30 centimetres.

> Each segment has a pair of parapodia, a structure for locomotion, clusters of stinging white bristles, and red or orange gills all in bilateral position.

You can see [this post from the Malta Independent](https://www.independent.com.mt/articles/2019-07-09/local-news/Beware-This-little-fellow-could-cause-you-some-pain-6736210623) warning people who hang out in tidal areas *in Malta* about this [polychaete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polychaete) worm -- it's bristles can inject a neurotoxin which can cause intense irritation/burning and possible nausea and dizziness.

Also, FYI, the whitish elliptic shape on the second body segment closest to your keys is the mouth. See [here](https://www.snorkelstj.com/bearded-fireworm-cool.html) for some images of this mouth in action!

Comment: @Thomas. Thanks for accepting my answer -- hope it helps! Please consider upvoting, too :)